# Organization browser in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

This should be something simple, I have read a lot about the organization browser webpart, its a nice silverlight app that shows the hierarchy of people on the company, however I have no idea where you can edit/know the hierarchy, who is boss of who? where can I edit that?

What about if the users are coming from active directory? I suppose the first time it synchronizes there is no info at all about hierarchies.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The org Browser pulls information from the User Profile store which in turn syncs with Active Directory.

You can also use this web part in your portal:

http://www.tcscblog.com/2011/04/11/using-the-sharepoint-2010-organization-browser-in-another-web-application/

Comment: but correct me if I am wrong, Active directory does not have the information of who is boss of who, how can I edit that information?

Comment: AD has a manager field, which is commonly used as the "Boss" - it's how the org browser works in SharePoint as default.